# How to prevent Renovate from updating dependencies which are not compatible with other dependencies?

Tags: .net, nuget, renovate

I have implemented Renovate, but am stumbling on the following case (for nuget packages):

Package A:
AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute 4.17.0
Dependencies: NSubstitute (>= 2.0.3 && < 5.0.0)

Package B:
NSubstitute 4.4.0

Renovate tries to upgrade NSubstitute to 5.0.0, but that would break AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute.

I know i can block the NSubstitute package to 4.4.0 in the renovate.json file with a packagerule, but that would require me to update this rule each time AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute changes.

Is there a way to configure renovate so that it takes this relation into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on the github repo of renovate [here](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/20532):

> not yet, you can workaround with dashboard approval for major updates.